# Iterating over list in Drools' when condition

Tags: drools

I have a class hierarchy as below:

```
class Order{
    List<Item> items;
    boolean eligibility;
    //geters and setters
}

class Item{
    boolean eligibility;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, what I want to do is set the eligibility status of an order based on the eligibility status of its items. If all the items in an order has eligibility as false, then the order's eligibility should be set to false. Based on another post, I wrote a rule like this:

```
rule "Check order eligibility based on item eligibility"
dialect "java"
    when
        $order : Order($items : items)
            Boolean(booleanValue)       
            from accumulate(
                init(int eligibleItems = 0;),  
                action(for(Object item:$items) 
                        if(((Item)item).getEligibility()) eligibleItems++;
                    ),
                result(eligibleItems == 0)
            )
    then
        $order.setEligibility(false);
end
```

However, when I run this I keep getting `mismatched input 'eligibleItems' in rule`. How else can I iterate over a list inside a `when` condition? I'm using Drools 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the error, look at this part of the rule:

```
        Boolean(booleanValue)       
        from accumulate(
            init(int eligibleItems = 0;),
```

The syntax of an *accumulate* using init-action-result requires a *pattern* right after the opening parenthesis after the keyword **accumulate**. Hence the syntax error. (You can see the reason why it says when it says when you match `init` with a pattern type name: the parser can't continue at `eligibleItems`.)

Rather than try and fix it, the rule can be written in a much simpler way:

```
rule "Check order eligibility based on item eligibility"
when
  $order : Order($items : items, eligibility )
  not Item( eligibility ) from $items
then
  modify( $order ){ setEligibility(false) }
end
```

It ascertains that there is no Item with eligibility set to true among the ones of an order. Just in case you want to make the change visible to the IE, I've used a modify and added a constraint to avoid looping.