# Drools passing List of Different data types to drl file

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules

I want to pass a list of different data object types to drools engine and be able to create rules by identifying the data object from that list. currently, I am only able to iterate list of the same data object type. it is as

```
rule "test"
    when
        $l:TaxList($k : list)
        $a:TaxReciever() from $k
    then
        $a.setAmount(100000000);
end
```

now I want to know how to iterate list containing different types of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drools get first element of List in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085312/drools-get-first-element-of-list-in-where-clause)

Comment: if you want to check for if the list element is an instance of some data object. you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085312/drools-get-first-element-of-list-in-where-clause/59101518#59101518.

Comment: can you write the syntax on how to use casting i tried this but its not working 
     $a:Object()#TaxReciever() from $k

Comment: you cannot directly convert objects in drools when using #. You should have an event where you can convert to your desired type. Check the answer in the link 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641183/iterating-over-list-in-drools-when-condition

Comment: i didn't get it, can you please explain here , how can i use it in my case

Comment: i can already iterate list of one object type as i  have written above, what i want to know is how will i iterate  if a pass a List<Object> list, it may contain different object types, how can i find its object types. and perform action on them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204406/discussion-between-sunil-d-bhagat-and-prog-g).